# what is the I/O Thread? is it a OS thread or User thread?

Tags: java, pthreads, posix, quarkus, vert.x

There is a moment where a server thread needs to accept a connection and read/write to it, is this thread what we call I/O Thread? Are I/O thread and EventLoop the same thing?

**EDIT:**
A bit more context, this is the article I was reading: [article](https://quarkus.io/blog/io-thread-benchmark/#hello-world-microbenchmark-io-thread-or-worker-thread)
The statement "the request is handled by the reactive engine on the IO thread" got me thinking on the question above

Comment: It's possible that IO involves a context switch, and other parts of the system are involved in IO, but "I/O Thread" misses the point.  As much as possible, the IO is done by your application and in the threads that you call those methods with.  At some point, the kernel probably gets involved and sets up a DMA transfer, but that happens as seldom as possible.

Comment: "The I/O thread" is the thread that you've decided to call "the I/O thread".  Presumably your design has it doing I/O, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I/O thread and EventLoop thread are used interchangebly.
Generally there is an event loop when it is using the Async/Event I/O Model once the kernel can send a message to the user process whenever I/O is ready/completed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as 'The' I/O thread. There isn't even such a thing as 'a' I/O thread.

A thread can do whatever it wants. You can have 1000 threads, all of them switching between reading a file (that'd be I/O by any sane definition of that word) and doing a complex calculation (that surely isn't I/O).

So, what's the I/O thread here? All of them? None of them? A nebulous definition where each thread is an I/O thread but only if they are on the 'read from file' part of the process?

The thing is, I/O thread is not a concept in the java lang spec nor is it a concept in any library I know of. It just doesn't matter. At best, the term is being used in some book, tutorial, or lecture as a 'shorthand' to mean something specific. The term is not, however, that kind of specific - from the context of said tutorial, book, or lecture it is probably easy to figure out what it means, but you did not provide this context, so who knows what 'I/O thread' is supposed to mean here.

> Are I/O thread and EventLoop the same thing?

For most definitions of the whatever I/O thread might mean, and for most definitions of what 'event loop' means, they are **the opposite**, actually.

> There is a moment where a server thread needs to accept a connection and read/write to it

One somewhat common setup is:

One thread calls `serverSocket.accept()` - this will block (freeze the thread) until a new connection shows up. At that point, the `accept()` method returns **and therefore no further socket connections can be accepted** and that's bad, it needs to get back into that `accept()` call asap. The network stack will not deny any incoming requests, it just holds on to them, it's like letting the phone ring for a bit.

Given that it needs to get back in there ASAP, it will fire up a new thread and hand it the socket that was just created, so that this thread can do do the job of reading/writing to that connecting entity, so that the 'socket accepting thread' can get back to calling `.accept()` as soon as feasible. A good setup will keep track of how many threads are currently actively dealing with open connections; if too many come in it should slow down or possibly start denying connections.

There isn't an event loop in this scenario. If you want to call the socket-accepting thread 'the I/O thread', that's ... a weird term to apply to that. Why not just call it the 'socket accepting thread', that's a heck of a lot clearer.

Comment: I've heard the term "net task" applied to the thread calling `accept()` and other server-socket-type methods (especially if using a `selector`), but that's a concept designed for an application, and it's more of an ad-hoc approach, something you do when the design seems to call for it.